# I want to run a script from another script, use the same version of perl, and reroute IO to a terminal-like textbox

Tags: linux, perl, stdout, stdin, tk-toolkit

I am somewhat familiar with various ways of calling a script from another one. I don't really need an overview of each, but I do have a few questions. Before that, though, I should tell you what my goal is.

I am working on a perl/tk program that: a) gathers information and puts it in a hash, and b) fires off other scripts that use the info hash, and some command line args. Each of these other scripts are available on the command line (using another command-line script) and need to stay that way. So I can't just put all that into a module and call it good.I do have the authority to alter the scripts, but, again, they must also be usable on the command line.

The current way of calling the other script is by using 'do', which means I can pass in the hash, and use the same version of perl (I think). But all the STDOUT (and STDERR too, I think) goes to the terminal.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate the output:

```
this_thing.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Tk;
my $mw = MainWindow->new; 
my $button = $mw->Button( 
    -text => 'start other thing', 
    -command => \&start, 
)->pack; 
my $text = $mw->Text()->pack; 
MainLoop; 

sub start { 
    my $script_path = 'this_other_thing.pl'; 
    if (not my $read = do $script_path) {  
        warn "couldn't parse $script_path: $@" if $@; 
        warn "couldn't do $script_path: $!" unless defined $read; 
        warn "couldn't run $script_path" unless $read; 
    } 
} 

this_other_thing.pl 
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use utf8; 

print "Hello World!\n";
```

How can I redirect the STDOUT and STDIN (for interactive scripts that need input) to the text box using the 'do' method? Is that even possible?

If I can't use the 'do' method, what method can redirect the STDIN and STDOUT, as well as enable passing the hash in and using the same version of perl?

**Edit:** I posted this same question at Perlmonks, at the link in the first comment. So far, the best response seems to use modules and have the child script just be a wrapper for the module. Other possible solutions are: ICP::Run(3) and ICP in general, Capture::Tiny and associated modules, and Tk::Filehandle. A solution was presented that redirects the output and error streams, but seems to not affect the input stream. It's also a bit kludgy and not recommended.

**Edit 2:** I'm posting this here because I can't answer my own question yet.
Thanks for your suggestions and advice. I went with a suggestion on Perlmonks. The suggestion was to turn the child scripts into modules, and use wrapper scripts around them for normal use. I would then simply be able to use the modules, and all the code is in one spot. This also ensures that I am not using different perls, I can route the output from the module anywhere I want, and passing that hash in is now very easy.

Comment: Yup, that's me. Thanks for looking there. I am looking at some of their answers. I was hoping to get some independent answers here though.

Comment: When crossposting it is polite to mention such, and even provide a link if possible.  *People* spend time responding, and don't like wasting time if a good answer has already provided you the help you need in some other forum.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. This is my first time posting and I didn't know the courtesies.

Answer (score 0):

To have both STDIN & STDOUT of a subprocess redirected, you should read the "Bidirectional Communication with Another Process" section of the perlipc man page: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/pod/perlipc.pod#Bidirectional_Communication_with_Another_Process

Using the same version of perl works by finding out the name of your perl interpreter, and calling it explicitly. $^X is probably what you want. It may or may not work on different operating systems.

Passing a hash into a subprocess does not work easily. You can print the contents of the hash into a file, and have the subprocess read & parse it. You might get away without using a file, by using the STDIN channel between the two processes, or you could open a separate pipe() for this purpose. Anyway, printing & parsing the data back cannot be avoided when using subprocesses, because the two processes use two perl interpreters, each having its own memory space, and not being able to see each other's variables.

You might avoid using a subprocess, by using fork() + eval() + require(). In that case, no separate perl interpreter will be involved, the forked interpreter will inherit the whole memory of your program with all variables, open file descriptors, sockets, etc. in it, including the hash to be passed. However, I don't see from where your second perl script could get its hash when started from CLI.

Comment: The perl/tk gui is going to replace a command line script, both of which gather info and sticks all that in a hash. Both also call other scripts to create various documents, filling in blanks with the hash info. 

Technically none of the child scripts are 'stand alone', but they still need to be able to be run from the gui and the command line script.

Comment: Then how are they expected to share those info gathered? If they are separate command line scripts, you can only share information between them using files.

Comment: The original gather script calls the other scripts using 'do'. The hash is a package variable and exported. Yeah, it still boggles my mind too how it all works.

Comment: But that doesn't work that way... you cannot 'export' a hash variable from a perl script into another.

Comment: In the gather script: It is package LC; it has @EXPORT = qw/%config/; use vars qw/%config/; and our %config;. In the other scripts, it's package main; use vars qw(%config); local *config = \%LC::config;. I don't pretend to know how it works, but it does.

Comment: Okay, then you have a magic package that handles this part of your problem. It's probably some local package, as CPAN does not seem to know about it.